# Best method to use Distance Matrix API for multiple items in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I know how to get the distance between two points. I usually use an AsyncTask to get the job done. However, now I've to put the code into an Adapter and I'm confused.

Will using an AsyncTask inside an adapter slow down the loading of the listview too much?
If it will, is there a better way to approach this problem?

The list will have a lot of items (over 50).

Code for the whole class. Some of it won't make sense. Work in progress.

```
public class CompanyTileAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<CompanyTile> companyList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public CompanyTileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CompanyTile> results)
    {
        companyList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context.getApplicationContext()));
    }

    @Override public int getCount()
    {
        return companyList.size();
    }

    @Override public Object getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return companyList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tile_company, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
            holder.type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companytype);
            holder.logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            holder.category = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText("Discount offered: " + companyList.get(position).getCompanyDiscout() + "%");
        holder.type.setText(companyList.get(position).getCompanyName());
        imageLoader.displayImage(companyList.get(position).getCompanyLogo(), holder.logo);
        imageLoader.displayImage(getCategoryImage(companyList.get(position).getCompanyType()), holder.category);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name;
        TextView type;
        ImageView logo;
        ImageView category;
    }

    private String getCategoryImage(String name)
    {
        String url = "";
        String cat = "";

        if (name.contains(" "))
        {
            String[] arr = name.split("\\s");
            cat = arr[0];
        }
        else
        {
            cat = name;
        }

        url = "http://***/imgTypeLogos/" + cat + ".png";

        return url;
    }

    private class GetDistanceTime extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {

        @Override protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String sDistance = "";
            String sTime = "";

            try
            {
                URL googleDMatrix = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + params[0]
                        + "&destinations=" + params[1] + "&language=en-UK&sensor=true");
                URLConnection tc = googleDMatrix.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                // take Google's legible JSON and turn it into one big string.
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                // turn that string into a JSON object
                JSONObject main = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                // now get the JSON array that's inside that object

                JSONArray rows_array = new JSONArray(main.getString("rows"));
                JSONObject elements_object = rows_array.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray elements_array = elements_object.getJSONArray("elements");
                JSONObject distance_object = elements_array.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONObject distance = distance_object.getJSONObject("distance");
                sDistance = distance.getString("text");

                JSONObject time = distance_object.getJSONObject("duration");
                sTime = distance.getString("text");             
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                sDistance = "N/A";
                sTime = "N/A";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return sDistance + ":" + sTime;
        }

        @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            String[] arr = result.split(":");
        }
    }

    private void setDistanceTimeValues(TextView dist, TextView time)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: Code for getting values from the Distance Matrix API?